# Tool for extracting the structure of a complex json object

Tags: json, schema

I have a big collection of json objects:

```
[
  {'hash1': {prop1: 24, prop2: 11}},
  {'hash2': {prop1: 15, prop2: 'val'}},
  {'hash3': {prop1: 20, prop2: 2}},
  // ...1000s more like that
  {'hash4012': {prop1: 54, prop2: 2}, prop3: 'some string'},
  {'hash4013': {prop1: 98, prop2: 4}},
  //... more
  {'hash8202': {prop1: 21, prop2: 82}, prop3: {'key': 'value'}},
  {'hash8203': {prop1: 25, prop2: 'val2'}},
  //... more
]
```

There is no schema defined anywhere in the project using this big hash.

I want a tool, when given the hash above, outputs something like this: (I don't care about the exact output, it is just to give you an idea)

```
[
  {'string':                                           // 100%
     {prop1: integer, prop2: integer(67%),string(33%)} // 98%
     {string: {prop1: integer, prop2: integer}, prop3: // 2%
        'some string'                                  // 50% (1%)
        {'key': 'value'}                               // 50% (1%)
     }
  } 
]
```

The idea is that I see the most common structure.

If such a tool doesn't exist, how would you implement it ?

(My use case is that I have mongo documents in an existing project. Because there is no schema anywhere, I have to guess the structure from production data. Scrolling through thousands of records is tedious).

Comment: what you're looking for is "pretty print", e.g. take a dump of some kind of data, and print it out nicely formatted.

Comment: @MarcB Pretty print would print the ~10k lines of my input hash. What I want is just the structure (as you see in my example, about 9 lines)

Answer (score 0):

Taking your example input and making it valid JSON gives this:

```
[
  {"hash1": {"prop1": 24, "prop2": 11}},
  {"hash2": {"prop1": 15, "prop2": "val"}},
  {"hash3": {"prop1": 20, "prop2": 2}},
  {"hash4012": {"prop1": 54, "prop2": 2}, "prop3": "some string"},
  {"hash4013": {"prop1": 98, "prop2": 4}},
  {"hash8202": {"prop1": 21, "prop2": 82}, "prop3": {"key": "value"}},
  {"hash8203": {"prop1": 25, "prop2": "val2"}}
]
```

Now if you prettyfy it (you can use: http://jsonprettyprint.com/), then run some regex replace to make the values into their type name (using a text editor or script), for example:

- Regex to replace strings: ':".+?"' => ':string'
- Regex to replace integers: ':[0-9]+?' => ':integer'

Then you can take the output and run it through: sort outputfile | uniq -c | sort -n -r. This will give you something like:

```
  7    {
  7          "prop1":integer,
  6    },
  6       }
  5          "prop2":integer
  2       },
  2          "prop2":string
  1 ]
  1 [
  1    }
  1       "prop3":string
  1       "prop3":{
  1       "hash8203":{
  1       "hash8202":{
  1       "hash4013":{
  1       "hash4012":{
  1       "hash3":{
  1       "hash2":{
  1       "hash1":{
  1          "key":string
```

So looking at the top values will give you the most common property name and value type pairs. Using the indentation you can have a guestimate at where it is in the hierachy.